# Office 365 Calendar API - Attendees list ignored when creating event?

Tags: api, outlook, calendar, office365

I am facing a strange issue with this API - when posting a request to create an event in Outlook Calendar, the response I get never includes the Attendees I have specified. It will only show the calendar owner, through which the API call is made. Besides, other fields (Subject, Start/End, BodyPreview etc) seem to be properly passed.

Even using the example provided by in the documentation, I get this strange result.  If anyone has a hint on that it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Example request below:

```
event_outlook={
"Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
"Body": {
"ContentType": "HTML",
"Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
},
"Start": {
  "DateTime": "2016-05-06T12:00:00",
  "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"End": {
  "DateTime": "2016-05-06T13:00:00",
  "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"Attendees": [
{
  "EmailAddress": {
    "Address": "janets@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Name": "Janet Schorr"
  },
  "Type": "Required"
}
]
}
```

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesEvent](http://API%20reference)

Answer (score 0):

Which account are you using to create the event? Is it an office 365 account or an outlook.com account? There is a known issue with creating events using an outlook.com (or other non-office 365 account) where the attendees list gets replaced with the organizer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm indeed creating the events using an outlook.com account. Would you know by any chance if there is a work-around to avoid this issue, still using an outlook.com account?

Comment: Hello @Shreedevi, sorry to insist but do you have any more insights on the above? I am working on an app that integrates Outlook calendar so this issue is pretty annoying! Thanks again